# How to debug Safari web apps on Mac?

Tags: safari, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a [Safari web app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/104996) on Mac (created by `File` → `Save to Dock`). I encountered a few bugs that only occur in the web app, not in the website version. It seems I can't open the web console in the web app to see what goes wrong. I wonder what's the best way to debug Safari web apps? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the inspector remotely from a Mac. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333873/wirelessly-debug-safari-web-app-running-on-ios-using-safari-on-macos

Comment: Thanks! I think that question refers to Safari web apps on iOS. I am having issues with Safari web apps on Mac. I have clarified it in the question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same tool in Safari as for debugging on iOS to debug in a macOS Safari Web App.

1. On macOS, launch Safari and in the Menu bar, go to Preferences → Advanced and check **Show features for web developers**.
   [image: Safari Settings]
2. In the menu bar, click on **Develop** → [Your current device] → [Your web app]

[image: Developer menu in menu bar]

This will allow you to use all of the Safari web debugging tools with your web app.